# How to decide coordinates for widgets by using pack in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I don't want to use place because GUI is looking different on different platform. It is very difficult to place widgets with pack. I want to Label 4 will place under Label3, entry 1 under entry2 etc, but I couldn't succeed although there is extra space under them.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(padx=0,pady=0,ipadx=width,ipady=height)

label1 = Label(canvas)
label1.pack(padx = 0, pady= 0, ipadx=width,ipady=10)

label2 = Label(canvas ,text="Label2:")
label2.pack(anchor=NW,padx=30,pady=20)

panel = Label(canvas,background="black",text= " LARGE LABEL")
panel.pack(anchor=NW,padx=30,ipadx=200,ipady=200,pady=30)

label3 = Label(canvas ,text="Label3:")
label3.pack(anchor=NW,padx=30,side=LEFT,pady=20)
entry1 = Entry(canvas)
entry1.pack(anchor=NW,padx=10,side=LEFT,pady=20)
button1 = Button(canvas, text="Button1")
button1.pack(anchor=NW,side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=20)

label4 = Label(canvas ,text="Label4:")
label4.pack(anchor=NW,padx=30,side=LEFT,pady=20)
entry2 = Entry(canvas)
entry2.pack(anchor=NW,padx=10,side=LEFT,pady=20)
button2 = Button(canvas, text="Button2")
button2.pack(anchor=NW,side=LEFT,padx=10,pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the image there I used place for label4, button2 and entry2. But it is not working when I use pack.

[im](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz2gC.png)

Comment: Why are you putting the widgets inside a `Canvas`? And then using `.pack` on them. Please look at some `tkinter` tutorials. Also look at what `Frame`s are.

Comment: @TheLizzard You are right but I have also an image in background that's why I didn't use Frame

Comment: @Stefan: In that case, you should post code in your question that does that.

Comment: Can you show us a drawing of  how you want the UI to look? It's not clear why you're putting a big black empty label in the middle. Also, why are you using padding the black rectangle bigger, instead of just literally making it bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to decide coordinates for widgets by using pack in tkinter?

As a general rule, you do *not* need to decide coordinates for widgets using `pack` and `grid`. Having to manually pick coordinates is most often the most difficult way to arrange widgets in a window.

With both of `pack` and `grid`, you're describing relative relationships between widgets. You do this by finding logical groupings of widgets and laying them out in relation to each other. With `pack` you're deciding whether widgets are added to the left, right, top, or bottom of their parent. With `grid` you're organizing widgets in horizontal and vertical rows and columns.

In your code you're attempting to use `pack`, but it seems like you want to align at least some of the widgets in a grid -- specifically, label3 and albel4, and the entry and button widgets. Because of that, `grid` seems like the more natural choice for your program.

You seem to have at least three columns in the most complicated section of the UI: one for label3 and label4, one for the entries, and one for the buttons. I recommend giving a fourth column to act as a buffer to take up the extra space, though I do this not understanding exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Without knowing more specifics, this is just an illustration of what can be done with `grid`. I've also made it so that the window is *not* fullscreen since that makes it tough to debug. However, this design expands in a reasonable way when you resize the window.

Also, since it seems that all widgets are inside a canvas for some reason, you can use `pack` to get that canvas to fill the whole window by adjusting its options:

```
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(padx=0,pady=0,fill="both", expand=True)
```

Now, you can strip out all of the other calls to `pack` and replace them with this block of code. I strongly encourage you to group your calls to `pack` or  `place` together rather than interleaved with the code that creates the widgets. It makes it much easier to visualize the layout in the code.

```
# give the row with the big black label all of
# the extra space
canvas.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
canvas.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

label1.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
panel.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="nsew", padx=30, pady=30)
label3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e")
label4.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="e")
entry1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="ew")
entry2.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="ew")
button1.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky="w")
button2.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky="w")
```

This results in a window that looks like this, with the black area growing or shrinking as you resize the window:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: A suggestion: change that `Canvas` to a `Frame`.

Comment: @TheLizzard: without knowing what they actually want, I choose to leave it as a `Canvas` so that the answer can focus on the widget layout rather than a critique of his code as a whole.

Comment: @BryanOakley I knew that grid is also an option. But now I understand how pack is working. Thank you so much thanks for information.